# How to select data between two dates using only the start date?

Tags: postgresql

I have problem select data between two dates if the only start_date is available.

The example I want to see is what discount_nr was active between 2020-07-01 and 2020-07-15 or only one day 2020-07-14. I tried different solutions, date range, generate series, and so on, but was still not able to get it to work.

Table only have start dates, no end dates

Example:

```
discount_nr, start_date
1, 2020-06-30
2, 2020-07-03
3, 2020-07-10
4, 2020-07-15
```

Comment: `what discount_nr was active between 2020-07-01 and 2020-07-15` Is that inclusive? Is the result 1, 2, and 3? Or 1, 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: Result should be numbers 2, 3, 4

Comment: Are you sure? If 1 starts on 2020-06-30 and 2 starts on 2020-07-03, 2020-07-01 falls within 1.

Comment: My bad, you are right

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the end dates by looking at the start date of the next row. This is done with `lead`. `lead(start_date) over(order by start_date asc)` will get you the start_date of the next row. If we take 1 day from that we'll get the inclusive end date.

Rather than separate start/end columns, a single daterange column is easier to work with. You can use that as a CTE or create a view.

```
create view discount_durations as
select
  id,
  daterange(
    start_date,
    lead(start_date) over(order by start_date asc)
  ) as duration
from discounts
```

Now querying it is easy using [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-range.html). `@>` to check if the range contains a date.

```
select *
from discount_durations
where duration @> '2020-07-14'::date
```

And use `&&` to see if they have any overlap.

```
select *
from discount_durations
where duration && daterange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-15');
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d01ff3d0df3084a7292fd491426305a7)

Comment: This seems to be working after some modification (Bad example description, dates are stored as timestamps and I need to use tsrange)
I discovered someday have two discounts at the same time active, then the duration calculation is wrong.

Comment: @MrSumsar If you're allowed to have two discounts at the same time, is the assumption that one discount ends when another starts true? If you're not allowed and it's just a mistake in the data, add a unique index to prevent having two indexes on the same day. `create unique index one_discount_per_day on discounts(date_trunc('day', start_date))`

Comment: [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bf7271c8b23caef910743c88dffc5938).

Comment: I still need both id numbers. There is some rule, that if two discounts were the same day bigger id(last one) is active, but that I don't asked first, I try to filter them out myself. My first goal is still how to find active discount number(s) specific day or dates frame.


`select discount_nr from (
 select discount_nr ,
   tsrange(
     start_date,
     lead(start_date) over(order by valid_from asc)
  ) as duration
from discounts
) discount_durations
where duration && tsrange('2021-07-15', '2021-07-16'::date + interval '1 day')`

Comment: @MrSumsar Removing the duplicates and adding a unique index so more duplicates cannot be added will make working with the discounts easier. If that's not possible and duplicates are gonna happen, you can use `row_number` to order by ID by day. `row_number() over(partition by start_date::date order by id desc) as precedence` then add `where precedence = 1` to get the highest ID per day. Or by highest discount `row_number() over(partition by start_date::date order by amount desc) as precedence`. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=865a836346469a06ee946bc23bb0e2c8)